# Automatically rescale Google Chrome between different monitors

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, display, display-resolution, scaling

My laptop has a 4K monitor, while my external display is only 1920x1080. When I'm connected to the external monitor and I open Chrome it looks Ok. However, when I switch off the external monitor and try to work using internal one(4K) chrome icons look super small. My Chrome version is 56.0.2924.87, which based on the articles I found, should be able to auto-rescale and all that.
What's wrong with it? Why is it so hard? Scaling is always such a complicated task on Ubuntu, when it works out of the box with zero effort on other OS.

Comment: HiDPI/4k scaling in general is just weird on Linux as a whole.

Comment: It has sadly always been like that when it comes to Chrome + Ubuntu + Scaling. Basically, Chrome never re-scales once monitors have been unplugged/plugged in/turned on/off. The only way to get around this is to quit Chrome completely (even the background task) once you have changed monitors, and then restart it. Then it will start with the correct scaling. This of course only happens if you use 2 or more monitors with different scaling (such as a small FullHD laptop monitor + a 4k). I really hope Ubuntu/Chrome improves on this in the near future since it's an insanely common scenario.

Comment: [Cool space sounds] Popping in from 2023 to say this still isn't fixed sorry, the future has AI search though